# unable to access invoke firebase http end point

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions

I am writing a firebase function and trying to make it available as an HTTP endpoint. But when I try to access I get the error "Your client does not have permission to get URL /getDetails from this server."

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const cors = require('cors');

var express = require('express')
var app = express();


'use strict';
app.use(cors);
app.get('/getDetails', function (req, res) {

res.writeHead(200);
var jsonObj = {
    fName: 'Karthik',
    lName: 'Mannepalli'
};
res.end(JSON.stringify(jsonObj));
});

exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

I expect the output {"fName":"Karthik","lName":"Mannepalli"} but what I get is Error: Forbidden

But the following code gives me the right output. In the below code I am not using express

```
exports.getDetails = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
const original = req.query.text;
res.writeHead(200);
var jsonObj = {
    fName: 'Karthik',
    lName: 'Mannepalli'
};
res.end(JSON.stringify(jsonObj));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events .

```
    exports.date = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
      // ...
    });
```

> For example, the URL to invoke date() looks like this:
>
> `https://us-central1-<project-id>.cloudfunctions.net/date`

```
    const express = require('express');
    const cors = require('cors');
    
    const app = express();
    
    // Automatically allow cross-origin requests
    app.use(cors({ origin: true }));

    // Add middleware to authenticate requests
    app.use(myMiddleware);
    
    // build multiple CRUD interfaces:
    app.get('/:id', (req, res) => res.send(Widgets.getById(req.params.id)));
    app.post('/', (req, res) => res.send(Widgets.create()));
    app.put('/:id', (req, res) => res.send(Widgets.update(req.params.id, req.body)));
    app.delete('/:id', (req, res) => res.send(Widgets.delete(req.params.id)));
    app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send(Widgets.list()));
    
    // Expose Express API as a single Cloud Function:
    exports.widgets = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

> For example, the URL to invoke the getter in the Express app example above looks like this:
>
> `https://us-central1-<project-id>.cloudfunctions.net/widgets/<id>`

So in case of `exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);`, the get URL is `/app/getDetails`. Not `/getDetails`.

And in case of `exports.getDetails = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res)`, the get URL is `/getDetails`.

Comment: I did follow this tutorial from firebase documentation before posting the question here. But thanks for the last tip.

Comment: I finally made it work. All I had to do was to modify the below line 

    const cors = require('cors')({origin: true});

And also to follow @zkohi suggestion of using endpoint app/getDetails instead of just /getDetails

Answer (score 0):

The code for your cloud function is not looking familiar to me at all. I'm not sure which tutorial or documentation you're using, but it should be as simple as this...

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

exports.SomeFunction = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
   //Your function code
   res.status(200).end();
});
```

Try that code and let me know if you get any more errors.

Comment: Hello, I did use the code you have suggested. Please see my post (last piece of code) and it works fine. But I wanted to use express. I don't want to use the function name as the rest end point.

Comment: I see. I'm not familiar with express. I'm sorry I can't be of more help.