# When i run the firebase function in browser i am getting error : Cannot GET /testingtest

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

i am new in firebase function, i need help, when i run the function i am getting error : `Cannot GET /testingtest`, can anyone please tell me why i am getting this error, Here i have added my full code

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors({ origin: true }));

app.get('/widgets/testingtest', (req, res) => {
  res.send({ 'status': 0});
});
exports.widgets = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Answer (score 0):

Firebase functions need to be emulated locally to test. 
Please see the docs on firebase for this:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator

Install firebase cli:

```
npm install -g firebase-tools
```

Since you are currently testing https functions in your example these commands will work:

```
firebase emulators:start --only functions
```

and you will see the url to each https function which you can call from browser or postman etc.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message, it looks like you're trying to access `/testingtest`, but in your code, try:

```
app.get('/testingtest', (req, res) => {
  res.send({ 'status': 0});
});
```

Comment: Now i am getting error : Your client does not have permission to get URL /testing from this server

Comment: There seems to be a mismatch with the URL. In the code, we use `/testingtest` but it seems you're trying to access `/testing`.

Comment: No, i am trying to access with tryingtest

Comment: Ok, and is that locally or when it's deployed?

Answer (score 0):

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors({ origin: true }));

app.get('/testingtest', (req, res) => {
  res.send({ 'status': 0});
});
exports.widgets = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

The get URL is `/widgets/testingtest`. Not `/testingtest`.

See [unable to access invoke firebase http end point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56720331/unable-to-access-invoke-firebase-http-end-point/56721136#56721136)

Answer (score 0):

For those coming here in recent times, `firebase emulators:start` is default way to start if you use `firebase init` to create your firebase functions.

The reason for `Cannot /GET /*` could be the way firebase exports the api.

After creating the api,

```
app.get('/widgets/testingtest', (req, res) => {
  res.send({ 'status': 0});
});
```

when it is exported as `exports.widgets = functions.https.onRequest(app);`
the actual api becomes `widgets/widgets/testingtest` as firebase exports the api on `widgets`, (`export.widgets`).

You can remove the extra `widgets` from here:

```
app.get('/widgets/testingtest', (req, res) => {
  res.send({ 'status': 0});
});
```

which then becomes :

```
app.get('/testingtest', (req, res) => {
  res.send({ 'status': 0});
});
```

This will be available in `widgets/testingtest/`.